# NodeJS, Package, nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, nodemon, visual-web-developer

Many attempts were made on running my JS file using nodemon and node.js but to no avail. When running 'npm run testing.js' I get the following terminal messages...

```
> CypherNetwork@1.0.0 testing C:\CypherNetwork
> nodemon testing

C:\CypherNetwork\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js:15
  require('update-notifier')({ pkg }).notify();
                                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "testing"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! CypherNetwork@1.0.0 testing: `nodemon testing`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the CypherNetwork@1.0.0 testing script 'nodemon testing'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the CypherNetwork package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nodemon testing
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls CypherNetwork
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\CypherNetwork\npm-debug.log
```

this is most likely a package error but I see no errors in my json file.

json file:

```
{
  "name": "CypherNetwork",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "testing": "nodemon testing"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Mickell",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

JS file I am trying to run with npm...

```
const Cube = require('./block');

const cube = new Cube('somedata','test','lol','somedata');

console.log(cube.toString());
```

Error log...

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe' --nolazy --debug-brk=51265 testing.js
Debugger listening on port 51265
c:\CypherNetwork\block.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { class Cube
                                                              ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\CypherNetwork\testing.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Class contained in JS file made into a nodejs module...

```
class Cube
{
    constructor(timestamp,previousHash,hash,data)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.hash = hash;
        this.data = data;
    }
//to debug our values for what is in our block chain
    toString()
    {
        return `Block -
        Timestamp:---${this.timestamp}
        previousHash:${this.previousHash.substring(0,10)}
        hash:--------${this.hash.substring(0,10)}
        data:--------${this.data}
        `;
    }
}

//exports our class as a module to access it in other files
module.exports = Cube;
```

Error message...

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe' --nolazy --debug-brk=51281 block.js
Debugger listening on port 51281
c:\CypherNetwork\block.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { class Cube
                                                              ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:501:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

Help is much appreciated, as I wish to learn from my errors as a node noobie. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour of tampering, the issue was solved! Update NPM and node version that accept ES6 interpolation when using java classes. (I hope this helped anybody who was using a node version for ES5.)